# Android VirtualDisplay resize "on flight"

Tags: android, resize, video-streaming, android-mediaprojection, android-virtualdisplay

Recently in project I faced challenge of resizing `VirtualDisplay` "on flight". So the use case is :

- Start stream
- In undetermined period of stream there may come specific data which indicates that my streaming capabilities have changed
- Update `VirtualDisplay's` parameters without recreation, so that state loss is avoided

I've found in documentation for `VirtualDisplay` [resize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay#resize(int,%20int,%20int)) method, though it seems to have no effect on new parameters incoming. For implementation I am using

```
  virtualDisplay = mDisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay("DispName",
                        getResolution().getResolutionWidth(), getResolution().getResolutionHeight(),
                        getDisplayDensity(), inputSurface, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION);
```

where `inputSurface` is created by `mediaEncoder.createInputSurface()` and cofigured properly by this moment. So, the question is, how can I resize `VirtualDisplay`? I also didn't find any examples how to do it in official sources, would appreciate any help!

**UPDATE**
Just forgot to mention, I've put `Listener` for `VirtualDisplays` and `onChange` method is triggered, though check if actual metrics were changed shows negative results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering to my own question**

The [resize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay#resize(int,%20int,%20int)) method of `VirtualDisplay` works pretty fine, though it was from my side misunderstanding of how to achieve very specific behaviour, when only underlying layout changes it's size, though elements are keeping their properties on smaller window

So, in case if you want to get some kind of **"scalar"** resize (like everything comes bigger or smaller) you should call [resize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay#resize(int,%20int,%20int))

But, whenewer your project demands some kind of resizing **and making your controls

bigger, though screen comes smaller** you should check your extention of your concrete `Presentation` class linked with `VirtualDisplay` and just update your layout manually without having `VirtualDisplay` resized

```
public void resizeView(final int newWidth, final int newHeight) {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Constructor<? extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> ctor = 
                        mainView.getLayoutParams().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class);
                mainView.setLayoutParams(ctor.newInstance(newWidth, newHeight));
                mainView.requestLayout();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

where `uiHandler` could be simply obtained even in background with

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

I hope this would be useful for somebody!